# Best way of concatenating array of arrays and integers

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Given an array of different elements, arrays and integers, I would like to come up with an array of all the integers contained in the array:

```
x= [[ 1,2,3], 4, [5,6], 7, 8, [9]]
pretty(x) -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

I did manage to complete it with a rather ugly reduce, but I'd like to know if there is something prettier to do with it:

```
x.reduce((t, e) => {
        if (!e instanceof Array) [e];
        return t.concat(e);
    });
```

Any recommendation?

Thanks!

Comment: "pretty" here is synonymous with "flatten"

Comment: `x.flat()` should do it.

Comment: The `!e instanceof Array` statement will always be `false` because the `!` created a `boolean` which will never be an `Array`. Use `!(e instanceof Array)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
x= [[ 1,2,3], 4, [5,6], 7, 8, [9]]
x = x.flat(Infinity);
console.log(...x);
x = [[[1, 2, 3]]];
x = x.flat(Infinity);
console.log(...x);
```

Comment: Notice that this solution flattens only one layer of nested arrays:
`[[[1, 2, 3]]].flat()` returns `[[1, 2, 3]]`